# Proper way to delay multiple network object instantiation in unity/uLink

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a game using UNITY and uLink. When the player connects to the AUTHORITATIVE server, a call back function gets called on the server, then the server loops and instantiates all the network objects on the client for example Instantiate(player,clientPrefab,proxyPreFab,serverPrefab...); There are multiple objects of different kinds.

However each of the network objects being created are very CPU intensive, especially at creation time, so the game is almost frozen at the beginning for a long time maybe a minute.

So I want to have a delay between creating all the objects, giving them time to instantiate before creating other objects so the game doesnt get bogged down.

so the questions are (I am using C#) ....

1. I thought UNITY was single threaded, so while I'm in that function on the server that gets called when a player connects executing a delay between network instantiations, what if another player(s) try to connect what will happen? Will they get delayed for a long time until that function competes creating every network object for one player?
2. Is it better to create the delay on the server, or on the client between creating network objects for the authoritative game?
3. What is the proper way to do this?

thanks
rough

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept buffered RPC before they are executed and control whether you want to execute them now or handle it yourself later. You can use this feature to create a delay between the instantiations on the client side:

http://developer.muchdifferent.com/prevdevsite/api/ulink-1.5.8/

Creating the delay on the server side is not possible as long as you are using network instantiate.

However, considering that it takes a minute to instantiate network objects, i would probably start thinking about the number of objects and whether they all need to be networked in the first place. Plus whether the CPU intensive parts can be postponed to a later time. But this entirely depends on the type of game you are making.